# Special Characters in StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am using streamwriter to write a string into stream. Now when I access the data from the stream, it adds "\0\0\0" characters to end of the content. I have to append the stream contents, so it creates problem as I am not able to remove these characters by trim() or remove() or replace() methods.

Below is the code I am using:

**FOR WRITING :**

```
using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        try
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string str in files)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(str);
            }
            // writer.WriteLine(folderName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to write string. " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            mutex.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

**FOR READING :**

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string str = @"D:\Other Files\Test_Folder\New Text Document.txt";
 using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
                    sb.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    sb.ToString().Trim('\0');
                    sb.Append("\n" + str);
                }
```

How can I prevent this?

[UPDATES]
**Writing**

```
// Lock
            bool mutexCreated;
            Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, fileName, out mutexCreated);
            if (!mutexCreated)
                mutex = new Mutex(true);
            try
            {
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                            foreach (string str in files)
                            {
                                writer.Write(str);
                            }
                            writer.Flush();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to write string. " + ex);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                            mutex.WaitOne();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to monitor memory file. " + ex);
            }
```

**Reading**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string str = @"D:\Other Files\Test_Folder\New Text Document.txt";
            try
            {
                using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    System.IO.BinaryReader reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream);
                    sb.Append(reader.ReadString());
                    sb.Append("\n" + str);
                }
                using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream);
                    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
                }
                using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    System.IO.BinaryReader reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream);
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to monitor memory file. " + ex);
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried writer.Flush() after you've finished writing to the file?

Comment: Just tried with writer.Flush() but note working..

Comment: I don't think the stream adds anything to the end of the content. '\0\0\0\' terminator string depends on the encoding. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864246/getting-null-terminated-string-from-system-text-encoding-unicode-getstring) could be useful.

Comment: The `using()` implies a Flush, but maybe move the Mutex code outside of the writing block.

Comment: And create your Reader with an explicit Unicode encoding as well.

Comment: Mutex can be a problem? I have tried the Reader with Unicode Encoding. But no help.

Comment: Your current writing code waits on the mutex with the stream still open (and unflushed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your combination of a MMF and TextWriter/TextReader, especially ReadToEnd() is not a good match.

A textReader needs the EOF concept of the underlying file and a MMF just does not supply that in the same way. You will get your strings stuffed with `\0\0...` up to the capacity of the MMF.

As a possible fix:

- collect the strings to write in a StringBuilder
- use a BinaryWriter to write it as 1 string
- read it back with a BinaryReader.

Another options is to use WriteLine/ReadLine and define some EOF marker (empty line or special string).

The BinaryWriter will prefix the string with a length-prefix so that the Reader knows when to stop.

Comment: When I try to read from BinaryReader with ReadString() method, it returns only one first line. How can I retrieve all data from reader?

Comment: It should return the entire string, `'\n'` included. Check your writing code or post both pieces.

Comment: Edit your question, post a 2nd part.

Comment: I have just posted the writing and reading code. Please review. In the writing code, there are three files path, that I am writing to MMF file. And in reading code, first I am reading the existing MMF and then appending another file path into it.

Comment: Re the update: that's clear, you are writing multiple strings and reading just 1. Read my 1st and 2nd bullet again.

Comment: I did that as well. But it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was doing something wrong before. Its working now with StringBuilder.

Comment: Hi Henk, I have a problem. Can you please reply here or where I can talk to you regarding?

Comment: If you have a new problem, go through the steps of posting a new question. Make it clear and independent so others can help too.

Comment: I just wrote a question. Please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631778/consume-disposed-memory-mapped-file

Answer (score 4):

No '\0' are getting appended by StreamWriter.  These are just the content of the memory-mapped file, stuff that was there *before* you started writing.  The StreamReader needs an end-of-file indicator to know when the stop reading.  There isn't any in an mmf beyond the *size* of the section.  Like the 2nd argument you pass to MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(string, long).

Or in other words, you created a mmf that's too large to fit the stream.  Well, of course, you didn't have the time machine to guess how large to make it.  You definitely need to do something about it, trimming the zeros isn't good enough.  That goes wrong the second time you write a stream that's shorter.  The reader will now still sees the bytes from the previous stream content and they won't be zero.

This is otherwise a common headache with mmfs, they are just chunks of memory and a stream is a very poor abstraction of that.  One of the big reasons it took so long for mmfs to get supported by .NET, even though they are a very core OS feature.  You need pointers to map a mmf and that's just not well supported in a managed language.

I don't see a good way to teach StreamReader new tricks in this case.  Copying the bytes from the mmf into a MemoryStream would fix the problem but rather defeats the point of a mmf.

Consider using a pipe instead.