# Consume disposed Memory Mapped File

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

Please excuse me if this is a poor question as I am not good with memory mapped files. I am using memory mapped files in my project. I am tracking the files in progress and the file that has already processed in memory mapped files. I have two memory mapped files. In the first memory mapped file, I keep track of processed files and in the second memory mapped file, I keep track of files under processing. So when the processing is complete on a particular file, I make an entry in the first memory mapped file and remove the entry from the second mapped file. Now the problem is that, if all the files are processed, I am disposing the second memory mapped file object. But when the user adds more files for processing, then I am initializing a new object of memory mapped file with the same name as the second memory mapped file name was. And when I try to access this second file, it gives an exception **"safe handle has been closed"**.

**Please note: I have to dispose of the second Memory mapped file object.**

Please suggest.

**FIRST UPDATE**
Function that writes first memory mapped file

```
Public void WriteFile()
{
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
         {
              mmf1 = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Some File Name1");
              Class1 Class1obj = new Class1();
              string foldername = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
              Class1obj.CreateMMFFile1(foldername, mmf1, "MMF_IPC1");
         }
        Class1.RefreshExplorer();
}
```

Function that writes second memory mapped file:

```
public void ProcessFiles()
        {
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Some File Name");
                Class1 Class1obj = new Class1();
                string foldername = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                Class1obj.CreateMMFFile1(foldername, mmf, "MMF_IPC");
            }
            Class1.RefreshExplorer();            
        }
```

Function that append the first file and disposes the second file.

```
Public void AppendFile()
{

  Class1 Class1obj = new Class1();
  string foldername = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
  Class1obj.AppendToMMFFile(mmf1, "MMF_IPC1");
  Class1.RefreshExplorer();
  mmf.Dispose();

}
```

Now when the user adds new file for processing the **ProcessFiles()** function will be called, and I get an exception.
Let me know what else I can do to elaborate more on it.
 The **CreateMMFFile1()** and **CreateMMFFile()** are function that writes memory mapped files.

**Second UPDATE**
Here is the AppendToMMFFile function, that append the first MMF file data into second MMF file.

```
Public void AppendToMMFFile()
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string str = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    System.IO.BinaryReader reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
                    sb.Append(reader.ReadString());
                    sb.Append(str + "\r\n");
                }
                using (var stream = mmf1.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
                    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to monitor memory file. " + ex);
            }
}
```

Comment: please, we want code, not words.

Comment: I understand, But I can't post the whole project here.

Comment: indeed, post just the relevant code.

Comment: Since your problem is only with the second mapped file, you can leave out all the stuff dealing with the first file. Just a few snippets of how you map the second file, how you dispose of it and how you try to create the new mapping would suffice.

Comment: ok, I am editing my question.

Comment: Please check my question for updates.

Comment: A mmf is 99% of the time the wrong class to use, +/- 1%.  Make it work with regular files first.

Comment: actually, there are few shell extension being used that uses these memory mapped files. So that is the reason these files are there. But these extension has nothing to do with disposing and creation of these files. So there can be no problem in extension.

Comment: Please post all code related to creating, disposing and re-creating the mmf, and post the full error message.

Comment: We need to know what happens in `AppendToMMFFile`, for example. Do you create an accessor for writing? I think you have to. In that case try to dispose of that before calling `mmf.Dispose();`.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check now.

Comment: @Treb: Please read my question. I don't have problem in disposing the MMF object. But the problem is when I try to create a new object with the same file name that I have disposed of already. For example, I create a MMF file "ABC". And then I dispose it and when I again create its object with the same name as "ABC", it will give the error.

Comment: Any Idea? Please ask me if anything I can do to be more clear.

Comment: Well, the error message *safe handle has been closed* indicates that you are trying to access the file at some point after you called `mmf.Dispose()`. Step through `Class1obj.CreateMMFFile1` on the second call and have a close look at the objects there.

Answer (score 0):

I think `OpenExisting(String)` will open a *named MMF*, which is for sharing memory across processes. I think what you want is a MMF from disc like you get from `CreateFromFile(String)`. If you simply need a new MMF instance pass `null` as name to `OpenExisting(String)`.

Otherwise maybe you should advance your question, so we can better understand you usecase.

Comment: It seems likely the original poster has figured this out in the last 8 years.